# Chrome extention doesnot work after reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-chrome-extension

My code is working well, but when I reload the webpage the code won't work anymore. I also tried to use chrome.storage, but it still doesn't work. i want to when i reload page code will must work.What could be the cause of this issue? thanks for help!

popup.html:

```
 <div class="cursor-container">
  <!--start cursor colors pannel-->
     <div class="cursor-colors-icons grid">
           <p>Colors:</p>
         <div class="flex-container">
            <div ><img class="icon" src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></div>
            <div ><img class="icon" src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></div>
            <div ><img class="icon" src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></div>
            <div ><img class="icon"  src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></div>
            <div ><img class="icon" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAMAAADXqc3KAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAABC1BMVEUAAABVAY1OAH5SAIgAAIBiAaZLAHhRAIVZAJBjAKZJAHVQAIJRAIgAAP9iAaZPAH5SAIZjAKZMAHpRAIdVAI5mALNiAaZLAHZPAIRXAIxhAqVPAH9TAIhjAKViAaZNAHtTAIdgAJ9iAaZLAHdQAIJMAINjAKVQAIFVAIdiAaZjAKZMAHtRAIRVAIttALZiAaZMAH1TAItiAKVNAHpTAIZcAI9gAKpiAaZXAZBdAItiAqVjAaZmAJlkAKViAKViAaZiAaZiAJ1hAKdVAKpiAadhAKVhAKZiAaZkAKRpAKViAaZiAaZiAqVhAKZiAKNiAaZkAKhWAY5IAHJiAaZIAHNVAIxJAHRJAHMAAAAXOwsJAAAAUXRSTlMA6et8Arf6rhdI/tA8Adbodmr2oxIK7f3HNYvjZR/79ZkIrP3AJT7VSM5f9b9LB+fxN4D2lhkY+b4Los8FM1vD+A1UA95pdv4cEfTMl34n6SlsWPHfAAAAAWJLR0QAiAUdSAAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAAd0SU1FB+QCBQktGDCIqVAAAADTSURBVCjPbdLZVsIwEAbggpSCCrKKIoJQ3NjdAEF2RZC1M6Dv/yaaxLZpk9xlvpOTzD9RPN4DnyJbqgF+LSCBIBoAh0fHAoTCRABOIm6JIhOIxRMOSJ6aAqmzc17SaAnsLjI2XGY5Achd5U0poENAL14zuCGAe1vg+/aOyr0goFMooVN25UqVQq3OhN7z09AerIc9onnm6fmFb6XZ+pf2qyuXDqt339yB9Rj0xfQHpD4ciTAmoErmNXn/gw/ZiKeInzMZzL9wIf0UyhJXclhvtvz2F7hXRZckfgsmAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDIwLTAyLTA1VDA5OjQ1OjI0KzAwOjAwZX4sVQAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAyMC0wMi0wNVQwOTo0NToyNCswMDowMBQjlOkAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHd3dy5pbmtzY2FwZS5vcmeb7jwaAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" /></div>
         </div>
     </div>

  <!--start cartoon icons-->
     <div class="cursor-cartoon-icons grid">
           <p>animals:</p>
         <div class="flex-container">
            <div ><img class="icon"  src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></div>
            <div ><img class="icon" src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></div>
            <div ><img class="icon" src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></div>
            <div ><img class="icon" src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></div>
         </div>
     </div>

  <!--start funny icons-->
     <div class="cursor-funny-icons grid">
            <p>Funny:</p>
         <div class="flex-container">
             <div ><img class="icon" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAAAsQAAALEBxi1JjQAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAd3d3Lmlua3NjYXBlLm9yZ5vuPBoAAAUqSURBVEiJjZVdbBzVFcd/d7521tlkbRw73obgTUxAkA9HUaAC6qqJQvhoghDIfCQOIAGiqqhUpKqqeIvUqu1DoYoQLVTqQ41wBIiAmwcrSty0QaKhSDVg4xCMvZEde+ON411/7czszD19WO/ikKTJ/+2ee87/d86dmTuKayibze4QkQ7gh0DTYngC+BfwViqV+sf/q1dLF7LnyZWUwjamZs5k3vnzOdd1O4Hd1+ihOxaLPVW3a/8ablh2MzHzI/X3rguVTQtA7n8iDaUVBGGPFL2UDhYiV+RLYNO1JgQe8qfzJ6Ng5nbDU6ZS8Ql5sP0+tDmreg5lDLnvsZeRaBgxPgNSOp+ndMfWEeLx6zEvqya+Kdy2ZVgXCgApIj5HomHZ1f4rJbvax1CsBpBiEV0ohLkjb4NlWdcNAAiCqOGhDjGSSUvF45XomIHiP5WVeB5R85qxivno6Cjd3d14nneZn+d5dHd3Mzo6Wg44jhmtufGcFP2laZ8YiNuB4iiA+AH+j+4JAQqFAsePH2doaIje3l601tUqEeHEiRMMDQ1x7Ngx8vk8AH7b90tSWgQojiLuU4Y62jmP8A0AUUTQumE5wODgIFNTUwwMDDA+Pk4ul6sCJicnGRsbY2BggIsXL3L69GkASls2JYh0pYuv1dHO+co5v4Jp7ATWl25anQRobW1lZGQE13VpaWmhKVlL4tAH5eYefoD169fj+z51dXVs3ry5DGhprhURMIwzwKvlQRY1MTFxKjs+fufKxsbq883lcvT399PW1kbte0dI9PQCMPfADvKP7ubkyZNs3LiRhoYGAMIw5EIuR1Mq9e9UKnUXLH4Hizpl2vadYRhWAQ0NDWzfvr3c9XQevXjWKl/AsqzqXkVhGGJaFiLySSVWBURRdMC27d1a65sAE8Aaz7LirfcIbmlh9idPoxvqQSnmH/kxiQ97cL4aYmbfo4SrU4gIURRFtm2fjaLoQMX3kqsC4OzZsx1Ap+M4JF/5E+anfRSDgJrWTfitG0BBrG+Ahc++wHUc9NZWCr/4KUEQoLXeu3bt2q6lfpcBAIaHh8/HYrHG+Mefkvj9Qc7NL1AMAxI1NQDMF4vETJMbly1n/pc/Y+Hubfi+P7lu3bpV3/W6GuBeoCcejxtOXz/L//gmZM9TlPIrGFcGNDUy+/MX8Fs34HmeNgzj3nQ63XtdgEXIX4DnXNdFKYVRmMEePAOiKd12K7o2idYaz/MwTfOv6XT62Sv5XBUAkMlkDodh+LDjOFiWhVLldBGhVCoRBAGO4xxpbm7eczWPKwJkoN2h1toH6vlAVq3M+o+nA11vK6UQEQBi5lRpld2VcYwLOUTeIJvoUtveLF0TIGN721H8AVizNByRyAR6VagUOOq8ZTCX/k59BiUvqe91fbDUz1y6+F3vwd/8oKbrIBIlkQCMRLURg6DOVtP1lpquVwR1l5iHWQgna/H6nwj2vGZ81Hn4xGWA1N/kpe5zd/zaVPZCvZmZv0H6lGHWWRjVu/3KCnOEC194X841z7029oL+7dAzO1P7DkzPvn/gVPWI1h6SF5VwMNIoLxRmPNjf9L7/xi37bcw6A/E1zq0GTjMIUBqB4GuNcgyivO4YfDc8nHvQWe6CaytMhSC8OLxXva5a3pYdUv4fVKcJNUzOapaZBdpq+4KPZ7bYx7c+XrjdPZUQ4PNi29z9/+1M3pXsK/3zwlbHM1bQuExhGpfOpoWdal2X9AMbrjS9CCgFWiBfFPywHHdtSLoKQ32bcxX1/w/rPEdWjJgJMAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" /></div>
             <div ><img class="icon"  src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAAAhQAAAIUB4uz/wQAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAd3d3Lmlua3NjYXBlLm9yZ5vuPBoAAAQDSURBVEiJjZVLaFxlFMd/333MvTOTTJt3mjjRVGoSkoWx9RWKdNEHWFA3PgqCq9aahSi40JUvJBYUFSQ+N1YqVLMQaURbaaALRWl90ISK9kHbPDqZycwkk8zcO/fxubjpJJPpxBy4i3O+7/v/zncu53xCSkl1+0a9evLvT4u2vcsu2O2FJcsAQThq2GbEnNSN0Njte7oPw+NeNQVRDXD99NsH0onk0aVcQVsnA2piEbextfHptl0vH98w4OLoq3+kZlJ3+/56t1sxRRE0b2n6fev+17ZXrK0NXP3xjROzU8kNiW9qu4uBQ8PUtm7jxtTsPVd/eH10XUDypyM7E1PJ/RtKG7Byc1w/N4qVmwMgMZ16ePb0kYHVe8rqm0inTrpu1f9VYfYy4Ka5rkcqnT7VDNGKG8z9/O69C9ml8IbV19jAoWHi2/eTTeciibGh+ysAi4uLz29UbNPmCD297dTUmqXY9XOjLMz8C4DtuIM346US2YXizv8TVhRBe7yepuYYANu6WpmezJC4MV9WqmLRKWmVAEWruGU94WiNSbyjATOsI/QowoghrSztcUFsc4S5ZI5sZgnfl1j5QnsFIN7ZaudzC4ZludiWgxCCaI1ByAxRWxNCCAGqjjAbEFpQmtPnC8wv5Hj0gc3U1pp4XgPzmTxSqF4FwIhG5g1DjeG7QNADyXmXN49d4sDeTrb3tiFCUUAAcGUyy7ET4/T3tKDGbkO6FpqzRL2mIxW1WAEQZuNlIYiDBN/lwpU0vlQouvDF91fo7rqDmlAgnrccPvzqLIoiGOiPc+HyHD1bG0ELI8IgJX9VAKRXjAgtFGSo6Ax9/mvZfzj63XkGnwomwWcjf5LM5AH44MvfgvWhR1itVQHAsyVaqOS+crCsIRFC4PkSz/PZO9DJ3oFOqppnl+ZMCaBI/yJw302/Z2sjzrUExelk6ZyVmAGgY5VWqK0JvaOlTH9Zqxzg+86EIj0Qamljbuws+fFL1TMFIn13Uv/MqvElPXzfmagAmJo2YhfSb4lI08rh/m68RGZ9QH93mS8LaUxNHyndprTSffAf8K5JZ6kUMro60OtiqEbolp9eF8PoWilYcNa7FmitBQCGNPZhZd2gF0AYOtHdO0CteDZAVYju3oEw9MD3XbCyriGNfau3Vbxo9sRH70kn/4Iw6xChWgC81DyFX8ZxE8Hc11oaCD/Yh9q4Kci8mENaGYQeed/ofe7FdQEA1vjwcZz8E2gGilkH6nJ/lJkEr4hvZcC1QY98bfYNPrlWq+qjb1345CHh2N9Kz66D5TmkGoG0Z4PnABKhGhmpG4+ZPc+euZVOVcCyKYWJj18S0t+DdPuE5zUBSFVNIrRxKZRT4d7D7wB+NYH/AFc+ps+BEHo7AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" /></div>
             <div ><img class="icon" src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></div>
             <div ><img class="icon"  src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></div>
             <div ><img class="icon"  src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></div>
         </div>
     </div>

  </div>
```

popup-js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  let  icons =  document.getElementsByClassName('icon');

  for( let icon of icons){
   icon.addEventListener('click',function(){
       let imgSrc = icon.src;
       chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "changeCursor", img: imgSrc});

      })
    } 
 })
```

background-js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
 function({message, img}, sender, sendResponse) {

  if (message === "changeCursor"){

  chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    for (let i=0; i<tabs.length; ++i) {
      let imgSrc = img;
      chrome.storage.local.set({key: imgSrc}, function() {
        console.log('Value is set to ' + imgSrc);
      });
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id,{message: "startChangeCursor"} );

           }
      })
   }

});
```

content-js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function({message}, sender, sendResponse) {
if(message === "startChangeCursor"){
    chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
        $("body").css('cursor', `url(${result.key}) 1 1, auto`);
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Copy chrome.storage.local.get...... block to the start of content.js.

Comment: "the code won't work anymore" is too vague, we dont even know what your code should do yet. What did you expect to happen? how did the code fail? Were there any errors? etc..